# Python insert string with random mixture of " and ' to database

Tags: python-3.x, string, cockroachdb

I'm running the linux terminal command 'strings' on a file and storing the result, which is a series of readable strings, in a variable.  The results are also written to a text file.  I then need to upload the results to a database.  The problem is that the result often contains ' and " characters in an unpredictable order.  These cause an SQL error.  I've tried to string.replace with an empty string and a \ escape.  I've also tried """ or ''' round the string but neither work as I don't know which type of quotation mark will be first.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
fileName = filePath.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
stream = os.popen('strings ' + filePath)
output = stream.readlines()
file = open(filePath + "/" + fileName + "_StringsResults.txt", "w+")
for o in output:
            file.write(str(o))
            results += str(o)
file.close()

dsn = 'postgresql://###########@localhost:########/test?sslmode=disable'
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)

with conn.cursor() as cur:
      cur.execute(
         "UPSERT INTO test (testID) VALUES ('%s')" % (results))          
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Have you looked at prepared / parametrized sql's They save you all the trouble of having to clean your variable input as you dont actually pass it as part of the sql. Instead you prepare the sql with a place holder and then passs in the parameter later.

Comment: I haven't but I will.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: They just save you the hassle of having to escape special chars in your data when you pass the data as part of the sql

Answer (score 1):

yes that worked, thanks a million.  For anyone else who's interested the solution was roughly:

```
query = """UPSERT INTO test (testID) VALUES (%s)"""
#Connection code etc.
with conn.cursor() as cur:
      cur.execute(query, [results])
conn.commit()
```

The [] round the parameter was necessary to avoid a type error.